# jQuery Validate Show errors only if form has filled in fields?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I've implemented Validate successfully, and have an `errorContainer` set.  However, if I begin to fill out the form and then empty it (manually, I don't want a cancel button), the `errorContainer` stays visible, even though there are no errors.  Any ideas on why that is?  The `errorContainer` has `display:none` set in block CSS, which is successfully toggled when errors arise.

I've tried tweaking CSS, the jQuery Validate file, but to no avail.

Comment: Take a look at [this plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/), it might be helpful

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to view any of your code, but if you're validating on a button click the first time, change it to an "onChange" validation instead...?

Comment: Showing your code would help.